# C can not loop just one time

Tags: c, loops

code here:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define ROWS 6
    #define CHARS 10
    int main(void)
    {
        int row;
        char ch;

        for(row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", row);
            for(ch = 'A'; ch < ('A' + CHARS); ch++)
                printf("%c", ch);
            printf('\n');
        }
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

output here:

```
0
ABCDEF
```

i think the output similar like this:

```
0
ABCDEF
1
ABCDEF
2
ABCDEF
3
ABCDEF
4
ABCDEF
5
ABCDEF
```

question is why loop just one time.

Comment: And the question is??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"ABCDEF"` contains 6 chars, so you need to change

```
#define CHARS 10
```

to

```
#define CHARS 6
```

Also, the `printf` takes a string, so you should use `"\n"` instead of `'\n'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 6
#define CHARS 6 
int main(void)
{
    int row;
    char ch;

    for(row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", row);
        for(ch = 'A'; ch < ('A' + CHARS); ch++)
            printf("%c", ch);
        printf("\n"); // Should use double quotes here
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you ， i need a place to think about the rest of my life.

Comment: @tiw sure, no problem.  If it helps, you should accept the answer.